# Returning 1 of 2 Strings in if statments

Tags: java

I'm making a small zombie survival Sim and was trying to add a few special items that will increase the chance of survival. Normally within the run the humans have 10 days to survive and are given a gun to shoot zombies and if out of ammo then they use a blunt object with less damage but better accuracy.

In my personal class, that has the fight sequence method, I have a "specialReport" get method that I want to display to the console when the "katana" has been rolled and or when the "ZombieCure" has been rolled.

These items are set to roll with a random number generator and then get used when the value is  `== 1`

line 172-185 is where the `specialReport()` method is that I would like to have printed out in the driver class on line 37-38.

Originally I had to take the `zombieCureChance` generator and the `katanaDropProb` generator out of the While loop on line 81 or the PersonClass because I was not able to return their values because they where inside the scope of the While Loop.

But now that they are outside of the While Loop im not sure if the values for `zombieCureChance` and `katanaDropProb` are going to be regenerated with every iteration of a new day in the for loop on line 28 of the DriverClass.

Currently I don't have any errors showing up but the output is not what I need.

[image]

[image]

here is the code for the PersonClass...

```
package Zombie;

public class PersonClass {

    public static int humanHealth=2;
    public static int humanCount = ZombieUtil.START_POEPLE_COUNT;
    public static int ammo= 150;
    public static int availableFood = ZombieUtil.START_FOOD_COUNT;

    //PersonClass Constructor
    public PersonClass(int humanHealthIn, int humanCountIn, int ammoIn, int availableFoodIn) {
        humanHealth=humanHealthIn;
        humanCount=humanCountIn;
        ammo=ammoIn;
        availableFood=availableFoodIn;
    }

    public static void setHumanHealth(int humanHealth) {
        PersonClass.humanHealth = humanHealth;
    }

    public static int getHumanCount() {
        return humanCount;
    }

    public static void setHumanCount(int humanCount) {
        PersonClass.humanCount = humanCount;
    }

    public static int getAmmo() {
        return ammo;
    }

    public static void setAmmo(int ammo) {
        PersonClass.ammo = ammo;
    }

    public static int getAvailableFood() {
        return availableFood;
    }

    public static void setAvailableFood(int availableFood) {
        PersonClass.availableFood = availableFood;
    }

    public static int feedHumans(){
        PersonClass.availableFood = PersonClass.availableFood - PersonClass.humanCount;
        return availableFood;
    }

    public static int getCurrentHumanCount(){
        return humanCount;
    }

    public static int getAmmoCount(){
        return ammo;
    }

    public static int getHumanHealth(){
        return humanHealth;
    }

    public static int getZombieCureChance(){
        //Zombie cure / converter
        int zombieCureChance = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.ZOMBIECURE_CHANCE + 1));
        return zombieCureChance;
    }


    public static int getKatanaDropChance(){
        //katana weapon drop probability
        int katanaDropProb = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.KATANA_DROP_PROB +1));
        return  katanaDropProb;
    }



    public static int fight(){


        while (WorldClass.numZombies > 0){





            //katana hit probability
            int katanaHitProb = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.KATANAHIT_PROB +1));

            // 1-5 chance hit
            int gunHitProb = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.GUN_HIT_PROB +1));

            //blunt hit probability
            int bluntHitProb = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.BLUNT_HIT_PROB +1));

            // 1-2 death miss prob
            int missDeath = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.MISS_DEATH_PROB +1));


            int gunCritical = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.GUN_CRIT_PROB +1));

            int bluntCritical = (int) (Math.random() * (ZombieUtil.BLUNT_CRIT_PROB +1));

            //Zombiecure
            if (getZombieCureChance() == 1){
                WorldClass.numZombies--;
                PersonClass.humanCount++;
            }

            //katana drop
            if (getKatanaDropChance() == 1){
                //katana hits = instant kills
                if (katanaHitProb == 1){
                    WorldClass.numZombies-=2; //kills 2 zombies per slice
                }
                else{
                    PersonClass.humanHealth--;
                }
            }


            //Gun attack chance
            if (ammo > 0){
                if (gunHitProb == 1){
                    if (gunCritical == 1){
                        WorldClass.numZombies--;
                        ammo--;
                    }
                    else{
                        WorldClass.zombieHealth-=2;
                        ammo--;
                    }


                } else if (missDeath == 1) {
                    humanCount--;
                    ammo--;
                }

            }// end Gun attack

            //blunt weapon attack chance
            if (ammo <= 0) {
                if (bluntHitProb == 1){
                    if (bluntCritical == 1){
                        WorldClass.numZombies--;
                    }
                    else{
                        WorldClass.zombieHealth--;
                    }

                }
                else{
                    humanCount--;
                }
            } // end blunt attack

            //human health checker/life updater
            if (humanHealth <= 0){
                humanCount--;
            }

            //zombie health checker/life updater
            if (WorldClass.zombieHealth <= 0){
                WorldClass.numZombies--;
            }
        }//end while

        return humanCount;
    }// end fight method

    public static String specialReport(){
        if (getZombieCureChance() == 1){
            String specialReport = String.format("Nice!!! you found a cure vial! \n" +
                    "You cured one of the enemy zombies and gained an ally ! ");
            return specialReport();
        }
        else if (getKatanaDropChance() == 1){
            String specialReport = String.format("Wow!!! you found a katana!! you can now \n'" +
                    "eliminate 2 zombies per katana attack!!");
            return specialReport();
            }
        else{
            return "";
        }



        }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "\nHumans Health: "+humanHealth+"\n Number of Humans: "+humanCount+"\n " +
                "Ammo Value: "+ammo+"\n Available Food: "+availableFood+"\n\n";
    } //End PersonClass toString



}// End PersonClass
```

Here is the Driver Class ZombieDriver...

```
package Zombie;

import java.util.Scanner;



public class ZombieDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //WorldClass and PersonClass Object Creation
        WorldClass w1 =new WorldClass(3, WorldClass.getNumZombies(), WorldClass.numZombies, WorldClass.days);
        PersonClass p1 =new PersonClass(PersonClass.humanHealth, PersonClass.humanCount, PersonClass.ammo, PersonClass.availableFood);

        //toString execution
        System.out.println(w1);
        System.out.println(p1);


        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Would you like to play a zombie survival simulator?\n Please type [ y ] or [ n ]");

        String input = scan.nextLine();

        if (input.equals("y")){

            // 10 day simulation
            for (int i=0; i < ZombieUtil.NUM_DAYS; i++) {

                WorldClass.getNumZombies();

                int personCount = PersonClass.fight();

                PersonClass.feedHumans();

                //print out special Items that are found
                String specialReport = PersonClass.specialReport();
                System.out.printf("%n"+specialReport+"%n");

                //daily activity report
                String report = WorldClass.dayReport();
                System.out.printf("%n"+report+"%n");

                //IS THIS AN APPROPRIATE USE OF BREAKING THE LOOP? WITHOUT "BREAK"
                if (personCount <= 0) {
                    i= ZombieUtil.NUM_DAYS;
                }
            }

            if (PersonClass.humanCount > 0 && WorldClass.numZombies <= 0){
                System.out.printf("%n%nAwesome you survived 10 days against a horde of " +
                        "Zombies!!!!!");

            }
            else if (PersonClass.humanCount <= 0 || PersonClass.availableFood <= 0){
                System.out.printf("%n%nIm sorry no one survived the Zombie" +
                        "onslaught :( ");
            }

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing Zombie Simulator!!");
            //close program
        }


    }
}
```

And my Utility class has these final variables for tweaking the Sim to make it servivable...

```
package Zombie;

public class ZombieUtil {

    public static final int NUM_DAYS=10;
    public static final int START_FOOD_COUNT = 110;
    public static final int START_POEPLE_COUNT =40; //change these where it will be variable to service
    public static final int MIN_ZOMBIES=11;
    public static final int MAX_ZOMBIES=20;
    public static final int ZOMBIECURE_CHANCE=20;
    public static final int KATANA_DROP_PROB=15;
    public static final int KATANAHIT_PROB=1;
    public static final int GUN_HIT_PROB=3;
    public static final int GUN_CRIT_PROB = 2;
    public static final int BLUNT_HIT_PROB =2;
    public static final int BLUNT_CRIT_PROB=10;
    public static final int MISS_DEATH_PROB =2;



}
```

Comment: I have tried to change it. that's why I'm looking for some external input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was returning the method and not the variable for `specialReport`